# InvalidLambdaResponseException : Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement sign up using AWS amplify. Here is the code,

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp() {
    try {
        const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {
                email,         
                phone_number
            }
        });
        console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following 400 error,

> InvalidLambdaResponseException : Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there's a Sign-Up [lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) defined which is failing for some reason such as:

- a code problem in the lambda causing a premature end
- the response is not returned as expected: no return at all, returning with an invalid format or missing attributes in the response

You should check the lambda triggers in the userpool and check their cloudwatch logs for more information.

If the User is not created at all, most likely it's on the [Pre sign-up Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html).